# Identification of Serif Font with round "a"

Tags: fonts

Can anyone identify the font in the image below.  Finding a Serif font with a round a has proven difficult for me.  thanks

[image: Image of Font]

Comment: Cormorant Infant resembles it. Check if it's close enough. It's a part of a big family which contains also others with the wanted a

Comment: Yes, it's Cormorant, Infant variant.

Comment: Also, EB Garamond has a similar one but is more proportioned towards body text, whereas Cormorant is proportioned towards large headings. You might find it useful. Or a lot of other "Infant" or "Schoolbook" font variants. Bembo has one.